# How to update an activity from a customAdapter class?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I have a userinterface with some textviews and a listview. I would like to update my textviews if something specific occurs in the CustomAdapter class. An Event in my CustomAdapter class will trigger a change in my MyActivity class.

The listview gets its data from a json, that is fetched from a server. Now imagine that the json contains just numbers and those numbers are listet in the listview. Works fine. I calculate the max number, but I fail to update my textview which would display the max number.
I get a `NullPointerException`.  How do I keep that objectreference?

UserArrayAdapter.java

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        return displayStuff(dev, position, convertView, parent);        
    }
```

calls

```
private View displayStuff(LeDevice dev, int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  if(maxDevice ==null){
       callMethodInMainActivity.java to update a textview()
    }
}
```

switching to MainActivity.java

```
Textview tv_field;
public void callMethodInMainActivity.java to update a textview(){
  tv_field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_maxNumber);

            tv_field.setText(42); //!!NullPointer!!
}
```

I call a method in MainActivity from UserArrayAdapter and want to access tv_field. That's where I get the exception. If I would call the same method from my view by clicking a button, it works.

Comment: what about posting some code?

Comment: Where are you getting null pointer exception , On your text view which you want to update ?

Comment: There is lot of code. I will try to get the importent parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fire a broadcast message from your adapter and define a Broadcast receiver in your Activity to receive this broadcast.

**SEND BROADCAST-from adapter**

```
Intent i = new Intent("ALERT_CHANGE");
i.putExtra("DATA","News");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

**RECEIVE BROADCAST-in Activity**

```
    registerReceiver(uiUpdated, new IntentFilter("ALERT_CHANGE"));


    private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdated= new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
    String DATA = i.getStringExtra("Data");
    txt.settext(DATA);
    }
    };
```

**SECOND WAY**

Another way could be you can have a static reference of your textView in your Activity.Like:

```
public static TextView txt 
txt = (TextView) find...
```

then in your adapter you can reference to this txtView like:

```
Activity.txt.settext("smthn!");
```

Comment: did you see my updates? would your approach work there?

Comment: This(BroadcastReceiver), I guess is the most efficient way to send some messages between components. However, can you please explain why do you have a doubt. Humble Request :)

Comment: I am trying your second way and it looks promising. If this works, you are my hero for this week!!

Comment: Which one of the two worked out for you? I think the #1 is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks to achieve the same.

```
public interface Callback {

    void onSuccess(String status);

    void onFailure(String status);

}
```

Implement this in the class where you want to reflect the data.